jenkins change powershell core default terminal size on linux host
When using powershell core on a linux host Jenkins is truncating the output at 80 characters.
I found this post which describes how to resolve it on Windows, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37950957/how-do-i-stop-jenkins-truncating-wrapping-at-column-80, however it does not work on a linux host.
$host.UI.RawUI.BufferSize = New-Object System.Management.Automation.Host.Size(160,5000)
Exception setting "BufferSize": "Operation is not supported on this platform."

another potential clue is that while BufferSize cannot be changed, WindowSize can. If you try to do it from a jenkins call to pwsh though it results in
Exception setting "WindowSize": "Cannot set window size when console output has been redirected."

found an explanation https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/20110
